# 1920x1200 resolution shows black area on bottom right

Tags: 10.04, nvidia, display, resolution, monitor

I just bought a new 27 inches monitor, I plugged it in and ubuntu started with my **old monitor resolution (1440x900)**. So I went to the nvidia-xconfig (the default config tool wont work because I use a nvidia card), I set the resolution to auto and it selected **1920x1200** (I also tried selecting it manually and other resolutions higher than 1440, the problem is the same), but on screen the monitor only seems to be showing a 1440x900 rectangle and the rest of the screen (right bottom) is black, here's a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4GQn.png

Any resolution higher than 1440x900 have this problem, I have also tried pressing the "auto adjust" button on the monitor but that wont work. I am using ubuntu 10.04 with kernel 2.6.32-35-generic.

Any ideas how to solve it?

**Update:**

Here's my xorg.conf:

http://pastebin.com/2EGQA65p (It looks like it still have the settings for the 2 monitors from when I have them both connected, but now I have only the 27 inches one plugged in since a few days, I'd like to use both monitors at the same time but first I want the new one to work fine on full res)

New monitor: Samsung P2770H (27 inches)

Old monitor: LG L192WS (19 inches)

Video Card: XFX 8600GT

NVidia Driver Version: 195.36.24

Also wanted to add that the mouse cursor can move over the black area without disappearing.

---

**Update2:**

I went into nvidia-xconfig and changed the resolution to 1920x1200, then I clicked "Save to X configuration file", and unchecked the "merge with existing file" checkbox, this is the xorg.conf file created:

http://pastebin.com/RVrBDAv4

After this I used "sudo restart gdm", and when the login splash appeared **it was in 1920x1200 !**, I was so happy, but then I logged in, and the screen **changed to 1440x900** (screen filled, no black borders). nvidia-xconf shows 1440x900 as the current resolution but xorg.conf still has 1920x1200 set.

**What could be forcing the resolution to change after I login?** (solved)

---

**Update3:**

What was changing the resolution was monitors.xml file, I edited it using the values 1920x1200, and this time after login the resolution doesn't change but the black border like in the screenshot appears. **So the problem is still the black border in the bottom right.**

---

**Update4:**

**I found the cause!**, if I kill **compiz** the resolution works fine so I went to System > Preferences > Appearance > Visual Effects, and selected none. **Now it works fine!**. I am still curious what's causing it, I set it to normal and the problem occurs, I then went to CompizConfig Settings Manager and deselected all the effects, but the problem persists, the only workaround I found is setting the Visual Effects to none.

**What else could I try to find the real root of the problem?** Because I am still having some problems like when I put the mouse hover the shutdown tray icon all the icons changes positions and also colors, it's really weird.

Comment: Interesting. What monitor and what nvidia card ? Also , can you pastebin your xorg.conf

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I updated the question with that info, thanks.

Comment: You have two screen sections in your `xorg.conf`. Why is that?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison I haven't edited the file manually so I am not sure, I only used nvidia-xconfig, at first I had the 2 monitors connected to the video card, now I have only the new one.

Comment: Do both show up in `nvidia-xconfig`?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Only when they are both connected, so right now no, I only see the new samsung.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison I have updated the question with some interesting behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a solution but a workaround, I had to disable compiz Visual Effects.